# Does a reverse sql inspector exist for django & postgres

Tags: django, django-postgresql

Does a reverse sql inspector exist for django & postgres? Something that shows you what is the origin of the sql view in django?

Something like this: https://github.com/rory/django-sql-inspector, but for postgres.

(Please let me know if you don't know of one, because hearing a handful of respectable peeps say they haven't is better than silence.)

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest django-sql-stacktrace, "github.com/adw0rd/django-sql-stacktrace";. Beside this django.backend.db logger that you can configure in the setting along with django.request logger to inspect the sql trace. Here there is a sample logging: configuration:docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/logging/…. I hope this can be helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am familiar with '.query', but it doesn't quite suit my need. I am looking more for a way to identify where the sql is coming from -- so I identify the sql and having it point me to the origin. Suggestions?

Comment: I see what you mean. I can suggest django-sql-stacktrace, "https://github.com/adw0rd/django-sql-stacktrace". Beside this django.backend.db logger that you can configure in the setting along with django.request logger to inspect the sql trace. Here there is a sample logging: configuration:https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/logging/#configuring-logging. I hope this can be helpful.

Comment: thank you for that. That looks like what it will serve my need! (Can you edit your original post to include what is in your comment?)